# Testing with 3rd party services

Tags: specflow

I am developing a asp.net mvc site that depends deeply on a 3rd party web service.

I would like to know what is the best approach to develop this site since the web service is not ready yet and I can't wait it to be ready to start developing.

I am using Specflow and selenium to drive my development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you forgot to say is if the 3rd party web service is written by you or your collegues, or if it's completely external.

Anyway, it's still possible to work in parallel. What you need to do is to arrange reunions with the people designing the web service, and obtain/negotiate their specifications, and design interfaces for their service. These interfaces should not be subject to enormous changes afterwards, during the service development.

Once you have them, you can do your job in parallel. But if you can't have them, then forget it: You can't work.

Comment: The web service will be built by one of my colleagues. Yes, we can define an almost accurate interface. But I can't wait for the web service to be built so I can start developing the pages.

Comment: Yes sure. For that you need to use the interface. Whenever you need to call a webservice of your collegue, do a dummy output like `alert('webservice');` or anything like that. And if you need a response from the service, hard-code a dummy sample value in your program and go on with your development.